# Weird Behavior of C# or is it a mistake i did?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, razor, asp.net-4.0

Can anyone explain why this action returns ZERO results when "0" is passed to "page" parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchProperties(string id, string offerTypeID, string propertyTypeID, string page)
{
    int temp = 0;

    var props = from s in db.Properties
                    where s.Approved && s.Available
                    select s;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        Int32.TryParse(id, out temp);
        props = from s in props
                    where s.PropertyType.PropertyTypeCategoryID == temp
                    select s;

    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(offerTypeID))
    {
        Int32.TryParse(offerTypeID, out temp);
        props = from s in props
                    where s.OfferTypeID == temp
                    select s;
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyTypeID))
    {
        Int32.TryParse(propertyTypeID, out temp);
        props = from s in props
                    where s.PropertyTypeID == temp
                    select s;
    }

    props = props.OrderBy(s => s.PropertyID);

    int i = 0, skip = 0;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(page))
    {
          Int32.TryParse(page, out temp);
          skip = temp * 10;
    }
    else
    {
         skip = 0;
    }

    props = props.Skip(skip).Take(10);


    var marks = (from s in props.ToList()
                         select s);
    return Json(new { markers = marks });
}
```

Is it because i am re-using the temp variable to tryparse?
Please enlighten me because this piece of code doesnt throw any exception or caution but just returns zero records...

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and debugging? I ask this because your question about tryparse could be answered via stepping through the code.

Comment: how do you call this. what is the url?

Comment: Why are you both checking for null AND using TryParse? You could simply use TryParse to set a default value when it fails.

Comment: If you are expecting these values to be ints and not strings, why not change the signature of your method? The ModelBinder should correctly convert the strings to ints for you: `public ActionResult SearchProperties(int? id, int? offerTypeID, int? propertyTypeID, int? page)`

Comment: @olivehour - I just posted that as an answer. :-O

Comment: I really appreciate ur input guys but i am more interested in why this piece of code is not working?

Comment: @MrBoJangles I spent considerable amount of time debugging. believe me, it didnt help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is more complex that it needs to be.  Simplifying it should result in a correct result or, at least, make it easier to debug.  Let the framework do the conversion to `int` for you.  If the parameters aren't required, make them nullable.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SearchProperties(int? id, int? offerTypeID, int? propertyTypeID, int? page)
{

    var props = from s in db.Properties
                    where s.Approved && s.Available
                    select s;

    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        props = from s in props
                    where s.PropertyType.PropertyTypeCategoryID == id.Value
                    select s;
    }

    if (offerTypeID.HasValue)
    {
        props = from s in props
                    where s.OfferTypeID == offerTypeID.Value
                    select s;
    }

    if (propertyTypeID.HasValue)
    {
        props = from s in props
                    where s.PropertyTypeID == propertyTypeID.Value
                    select s;
    }

    props = props.OrderBy(s => s.PropertyID);

    // use null coalescing operator to default to 0
    page = page ?? 0;

    int skip = page * 10;

    props = props.Skip(skip).Take(10);


    var marks = (from s in props.ToList()
                         select s);
    return Json(new { markers = marks });
}
```

Comment: your solution is much more cleaner. I love it. but still u didnt explain that weird behavior. is it a bug or something in tryparse?

Comment: I can only surmise that the value of temp is set above somewhere to something other than zero, but that the parse operation on page fails while page is a non-empty string.  That would leave temp at its previous value, causing skip to be non-zero.  If you are going to use TryParse, there's no reason to check for null first and you should check whether the parse operation succeeds, assigning the correct default when it doesn't.  One way to check the existing code would be to change from TryParse to Parse and see if there is an exception thrown.  That would tell you where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely it relates to reusing the temp variable in TryParse, without really utilizing TryParse properly. If any of the parameters are non-null, non-empty, then no matter what it will still try to further limit your props query whether the TryParse succeeded or not.

What you should be doing is having the TryParse in a conditional statement any time you call it.

```
if(Int32.TryParse(propertyTypeID, out temp))
{
    props = ...
}
```

You can also short-circuit the evaluation into the initial conditional too, since you require BOTH that it be non-null or empty AND succeed with the parse:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) && Int32.TryParse(id, out temp))
{
    props = ...
}
```

So if it fails in parsing the string to an integer, then it won't bother with the conditional statement.

Comment: Sir I can assure u that the tryparse didnt fail. why whould it fail when i pass the string "0" to it?
u know, i just used new variable in each tryparse statement and it is working now... is it a bug in c#?!

Comment: I'm not saying the TryParse of "0" failed. I'm just saying that if, for some reason, one of the other IsNullOrEmpty checks pass but the TryParse fails, then it will still continue filtering. Have you tried taking the "Skip" out completely to see if any data shows up? Either way, you seem to have already resolved the issue, so please mark tvanfosson's suggestion as the answer (as it was the best overall suggestion). He explained the reason for this "bug", because the temp variable maintains its previous value if the TryParse fails. This is not a bug, but by design, so set temp beforehand.